# Insufficient Permission issues

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I have configured gcloud with correct project, service account and other configurations. Enabled Google API and ran application on GKE clusters.

I am facing the following logs

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/foo/o?projection=full&uploadType=multipart
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:555)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:475)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:592)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.create(HttpStorageRpc.java:305)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: What is the command you run/the action you tried to get this error message?

Comment: This looks like you are trying to write files to Google Cloud Storage. Your question does not have enough context to really debug this. Though if you are trying to write to GCS from an application in GKE, note that the default GKE scopes do not provide storage write permissions, only read